# How to prove $x^{\ln x} > \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2x} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, logarithms

How to prove the following? $$x^{\ln x} > \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2x}  \tag{1} $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+\setminus \{1\}$?

I could prove $ x^{\ln x} > x $ and
$ x^{\ln x} > x/2 $  (in the appropriate regions), 
using  $x^{\ln x - 1} > a$ for $a=1, 1/2$

but not $(1)$. I could do derivatives, but then the question becomes about comparing derivaties, which looks like a more difficult problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, for $t\ne 0$, we have
$$ e^{t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}}{n!}>
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cosh t.$$
Now take $t=\ln x$, to obtain the required inequality.

Note:

1. $\cosh t = \dfrac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$
2. The inequality turns into equality when $t=0$ which is $x=1$

Comment: don't mind me, just filling in parts of the answer.